# Rails 4, saving attributes nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have a model Job. A job require many skills. But when I'm trying to save my job it fails. I'm not sure I understand what I'm doing wrong.
My models:

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many    :job_skills
  has_many    :jobs, through: :job_skills

end

class JobSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :job

end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :job_skills, :inverse_of => :job
  has_many    :skills, through: :job_skills
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_skills
end
```

My view:

```
<%= form_for @job do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h4>General informations</h4>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :title %>
                <%= f.text_field :title, :autofocus => true, class:'form-control' %>
            </div><br />

            <%= f.fields_for :job_skills do |s| %>
                <%= s.text_field :id %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submit" style="position:relative;">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'button button-small' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :has_company?, :except => [:index, :show]

  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    @job.company_id = current_user.company_id
    @job.user_id = current_user.id
    if @job.save
      flash[:notice] = "This job offer has been saved."
      return redirect_to job_path(@job)
    else
      flash[:error] = @job.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  def new
    if current_user.company.present?
      @job = Job.new(email:current_user.email)
      @job.job_skill.build 
    else
      flash[:error] = "You need to create a company before posting a job"
      return redirect_to new_company_path()
    end
  end

  private

  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:status, :title, :description, :remote ,:job_type, :visa_sponsor, :email, :salary_max, :salary_min, :country, :state, :city, job_skill_attributes: [:id])
  end

end
```

So, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, when I'm trying to save I get the following error:

> @job = Job.new(job_params)
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Exception:
>
> Couldn't find Skill with ID=4 for Job with ID= nil

Comment: Probably dubplicate of [Rails: multi level nested Forms (accepts nested attributes)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23952099/1065703

Comment: @MartinM Hum, an after create wont work since the issue happens on the Job.new()

Comment: Shouldn't it be `has_many :job_skills` in the first model, not ` `has_many    :jobskills`?

Comment: Also I don't think you need those `inverse_of` arguments, and `has_many    :job_skill` in the third model should be pluralized (`has_many    :job_skills`)

Comment: Aaaand not relevant to your code, but the word "information" has no plural - it should be "General information" not "General informations"!

Comment: @GeorgeMillo Thanks! fixed the errors in my code and edited my post, unfortunately, the error remain

Answer (score 0):

Your pieces of code are a bit confusing for me.
It seems, that you want to create a job and define, what skills are needed for this job.
Why do you need nested attributes?
Normally, you

- either edit a list of all the skills, that are probably needed for a job and then assign the propper skills to that job, than you have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship and can use form helpers for collections. In this case, you don't need a model `JobSkill` (but a table `jobs_skills` to store the relationship and is handles transparently by Rails)
- or add random skills to a job, then your job `has_may :skills` and every skill belongs to exactly one job. Here you can use nested attributes. And then you need a way to add nested skill instances i.e. with [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). Again, you don't need a model `JobSkill`.

Which one is your usecase, so I can explain it in more detail.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb now. I do need has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.
I'll try with this. Thanks a lot!