# Multi Model Nested Select type Drop Down Form Submissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I asked this question previously here: [Submit additional forms to another model with native model from the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450641/submit-additional-forms-to-another-model-with-native-model-from-the-controller/27479384#27479384)

and got some answers with the help of which I came with some solution and some problems.
Here is the problem:

I have 2 models, 
and I the submission form's Model A belongs to another Model B.
Now Model B is presented as a select drop down tag.

I want this form submission to submit and associate each new entry in Model A
 and refer to Model B's id automatically. This is the short version. 
Here is how the story unfolds:

Model A is RetailerPage

```
class RetailerPage < ActiveRecord::Base
    ..some code..
    belongs_to :retailer_name
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :retailer_name
end
```

Model B is RetailerName

```
class RetailerName < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :retailer_pages
    validates_presence_of :name
end
```

retailer_pages_controller where I want the submission is:

```
class RetailerPagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_retailer_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @retailer_page = RetailerPage.new
    @retailer_name = RetailerName.all.map {|retailer| [retailer.name, retailer.id]}
    some code

  def create
    @retailer_page = RetailerPage.new(retailer_page_params)
    some code


  def retailer_page_params
      params.require(:retailer_page).permit(:fname, :lname, :email, :contact, retailer_name_attributes: [:name, :id])
  end
```

The respective view has:([this](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/advanced-forms) came handy)

```
<%= f.select(:retailer_name_id, @retailer_name) %>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign Up", name: "Sign Up" %>
  </div>
```

I want, that when I submit, whatever Ive selected in the drop down menu should be stored as an association that belongs to Model RetailerName.

Is this possible? If some change is needed, please let me know. Ill appreciate that.

I have refered to [Rails: multi level nested Forms (accepts nested attributes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952099/rails-multi-level-nested-forms-accepts-nested-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accepts_nested_attributes` is not needed in this case. It is meant for [associating|editing|creating] other records within the parent form. Besides, it doesn't work from the `belongs_to` side of the relationship.

Your problem stems from that.

The `retailer_page_params` method is looking for `retailer_name_attributes` which aren't there due to the fact its not correctly setup in the form.

`retailer_name_id` is given in the form and thats what you need.

Change `retailer_page_params` to

```
params.require(:retailer_page).permit(:fname, :lname, :email, :contact, :retailer_name_id)
```

It should work after that.

Comment: Yes it works! Ok so when I defined @retailer_name = RetailerName.all.map  and had f.select associate, it saved as required in the params right? So please tell me when should I use accepts_nested_attributes. also if you could provide some dummy 101 resource on that??

Comment: ---The problem now that im having is each new record is being stored with "retailer_name_id"=>1; it should store in the next one!--- Ignore, it is working as it should

Comment: @user2290820 a good source of all stuff rails is rails casts. More specifically for nested models: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: As to when you should use it, it should be on a `has_[many|one]` association.